# iTunes store: App keyword search optimization. Strings intelligently indexed?

Tags: indexing, substring, keyword, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Does anyone know how App keywords are indexed against search terms in the iTunes store? Keyword characters allowed in iTunes Connect are limited, so listing combinations of search terms becomes factorially large. Say my app does "foo bar" and "goo bar", but some people may commonly search for "foobar" or "bar foo". Is it sufficient to enter:

```
foo, bar, goo
```

and hope that iTunes will do the appropriate substring matching, or to cover all my bases, should I enter:

```
foo bar, goo bar, foo, goo, bar, foobar, goobar, bar foo, bar goo, barfoo, bargoo
```

Can anyone shed some light on how intelligently search strings are matched to keywords?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should include "foo", "bar", "goo" and "foobar" since "foo" and "bar" are different from "foobar". I just remember being told that iTunes uses an old key word system. Include just the single word in the keywords and not "foo bar" and "goo bar" but "foo", "bar", and "goo". Makes sense? Hope I helped. :)